# How to add rotate and resize buttons to a view in android

Tags: android, android-studio, view, rotation, resize

[image: My Image Button Screen Shot]
I want to add resize & rotate buttons to my Image button. I have designed UI like in the SS. I have put all 3 image buttons to a relative layout & main button's height and width set to `MATCH_PARENT` Now I want to add the code for them. Currently I have succeed in implementation of resize button but only when rotation is 0. This is my resize button's  `onTouchListener` declaration.

```
View.OnTouchListener resizeListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent e) {


        RelativeLayout v = (RelativeLayout) view.getParent();
        switch (e.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                dX = v.getWidth() - e.getRawX();
                dY = v.getHeight() - e.getRawY();                 
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                x = (e.getRawX() + dX);
                y = (e.getRawY() + dY);
                lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int) x, (int) y);
                v.setLayoutParams(lp);
                break;
            default:
                return false;

        }

        return false;
    }
};
```

(I have declared variables as global. Declaration are not mentioned in the code)

This code works as I want but only when rotation of RelatieLayout is 0. Please suggest implementation to add my resize button to work in any rotation and implementation to add my rotate button to  rotate the view using one finger.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute aniamtion at the same time I think

But you can try this animation rotate counter and clockwise

```
public void rotate_Clockwise(View view) {
    ObjectAnimator rotate = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "rotation", 180f, 0f);
    rotate.setRepeatCount(10);
    rotate.setDuration(500);
    rotate.start();
}

 public void rorate_AntiClockwise(View view) {
    ObjectAnimator rotate = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "rotation", 0f, 180f);
    rotate.setRepeatCount(10);
    rotate.setDuration(500);
    rotate.start();
 }
```